# How to convert custom json format to coco format?

Tags: python, json, format

I have some question about how to convert custom json format to coco format.
I have custom json format, this is my custom json format.

```
{
    "Raw_Data_Info": {
        "Acknowledge": "1984",
        "Date": "2021-08-28",
        "Exposure_Time": "0.0006578947",
        "F_Stop": "227/100",
        "File_Extension": "mp4",
        "FPS": "30",
        "Inspection_Distance": "223",
        "ISO_ID": "50",
        "Location": "6895056-1",
        "Raw_Data_ID": "S-210828_N_C_3_R_66166895056",
        "Resolution": [
            1440,
            1080
        ],
        "Season": "summer",
        "Structure": "N",
        "Temperature": "30",
        "Time": "15:34:46"
    },
    "Source_Data_Info": {
        "File_Extension": "jpg",
        "Large_ID": "N",
        "Middle_ID": "C",
        "Shooting_ID": "R",
        "Source_Data_ID": "S-210828_N_C_3_R_66166895056-1"
    },
    "Learning_Data_Info": {
        "File_Extension": "json",
        "Json_Data_ID": "S-210828_N_C_3_R_66166895056-1",
        "Annotations": [
            {
                "Class_ID": "3",
                "Type": "polygon",
                "polygon": [
                    517,
                    711,
                    510,
                    715,
                    524,
                    723,
                    525,
                    777,
                    557,
                    783
```

I want to change to coco format like this.

```
{
  "version": "4.0.0",
  "flags": {},
  "shapes": [
    {
      "label": "person",
      "points": [
        [
          517,
          711
        ],
        [
          510,
          715
        ],
        [
          524,
          723
        ],
        [
          525,
          777
        ],
        [
          557,
          783
        ]
      ],
      "group_id": 0,
      "shape_type": "polygon",
      "flags": {}
    }
    
      ],
      "group_id": null,
      "shape_type": "polygon",
      "flags": {}
    }
  ],
  "imagePath": "2011_000003.jpg",
  "imageData": null,
  "imageHeight": 338,
  "imageWidth": 500
}
```

So, I changed like this

```
{
'version': '4.0.0', 
'flags': {}, 
'Shapes': {'points': [{'Type': 'polygon', 'polygon': [517, 711, 510, 715, 524, 723, 525, 777, 557, 783]
```

By yhis code

```
with open(json_files[0], 'r', encoding='UTF8') as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)
    json_data['version'] = "4.0.0"
    json_data['flags'] = {}
    del(json_data['Source_Data_Info'])
    del(json_data['Raw_Data_Info'])
    json_data['Learning_Data_Info'].pop('File_Extension')
    json_data['Learning_Data_Info'].pop('Json_Data_ID')
    json_data['Shapes'] = json_data.pop('Learning_Data_Info')
    for i in range(len(json_data['Shapes']['Annotations'])):
        json_data['Shapes']['Annotations'][i].pop('Class_ID')
        json_data['Shapes']['points'] = json_data['Shapes'].pop('Annotations')
```

But in 'Shapes' key I have to add square bracket. like this

```
"shapes": [
        {
          "label": "person",
          "points": [
            [
              517,
              711
            ]
```

How can I convert custom json format to coco format?
Thanks